esp32 (T8 S3 lilygo) doesn't work using Arduino framework
I have esp32 T8-S3 (lilygo) and the only way I can get it to work is using MicroPython with Thonny/VS Code using PyMakr.
I tried to start a project on Arduino IDE/PlatformIO (VS Code) but whenever I try to upload the code (not to open the monitor, once the code has been uploaded), it says it cannot open the port. The error on PlatformIO says:

A fatal error occurred: Could not open COMx, the port doesn't exist

I tried to change the number of the port (via device manager) as some posts suggested, but it didn't help.
However, the drivers are in fact okay since I can upload MicroPython sketches.
I tried with empty file code as well, but it makes no difference.
I tried to re-flash the firmware (using Thonny/esptool via cmd), to reinstall the drivers, and also tried a different board (same module) but it is still the same. Windows Device Manager recognises it properly.
I've worked a lot with different modules of esp32 (using both MicroPython and the Arduino framework), and I never had that problem before.
I currently try to get it to work on PlatformIO (VS Code, Windows)
platformui.ini file:
[platformio]
default_envs = dfrobot_firebeetle2_esp32s3

[env:dfrobot_firebeetle2_esp32s3]
platform = espressif32
board = dfrobot_firebeetle2_esp32s3
framework = arduino

upload_port = COM15
upload_speed = 921600
monitor_speed = 115200
build_flags =
    -DARDUINO_USB_CDC_ON_BOOT=1

I tried with different speeds as well, and made to difference.
Am I missing here something?

You provided no information other than saying it work on micro python but not on Arduino IDE or PlatformIO. On Arduino IDE, what is your configuration of Board and the rest of configurations? For PlatformIO, what is your platformio.ini looks like?

@hcheung you are right, I apologise. I added the content of my platformio.ini file. (For now, I think it's better if I stay with PlatformIO only, to first see if it works there)
I apologise if there is any information I did not add, it is my first question here.

Platformio/Arduino does not support the boards that you mentioned, so in order to use it, you must add your board to it.
It can be accessed as dfrobot_firebeetle2_esp32s3 for T8 S3 and esp32-c3-devkitm-1 for T8 C3 in platformio/arduino.
For platformio, you need to define it in platformio.ini file of your project
More information about how to use them is provided below.
For T8 S3 Visit LINK
For T8 C3 Visit LINK
add below config in platformio.ini file
    [platformio]
default_envs = dfrobot_firebeetle2_esp32s3

[env:dfrobot_firebeetle2_esp32s3]
platform = espressif32
board = dfrobot_firebeetle2_esp32s3
framework = arduino
platform = espressif32
monitor_port = COM15
upload_port = COM15
upload_speed = 921600
monitor_speed = 115200
build_flags = 
    -DARDUINO_USB_CDC_ON_BOOT=1 ;use the USB port as a serial port

Your baudrate should be initialise as given below in setup.
void setup() {
   Serial.begin(115200UL);
   while(!Serial);
}

You must need to open terminal at 115200

Thank you! I indeed tried to access it as dfrobot_firebeetle2_esp32s3, and followed the instruction on the GitHub page. (I now added the content of platformio.ini file to the question)
Still, nothing I try works, not even a bit. What else may I check?

Please look at this, i have modified some code


The default_envs was not supposed to be used the way you use it.

You need an extra build flag to use the USB as the Serial port as per how the T8 S3 is designed:


[platformio]
default_envs = dfrobot_firebeetle2_esp32s3

[env:dfrobot_firebeetle2_esp32s3]
platform = espressif32
board = dfrobot_firebeetle2_esp32s3
framework = arduino
platform = espressif32

upload_port = COM15
upload_speed = 921600
monitor_speed = 115200
build_flags = 
    -DARDUINO_USB_CDC_ON_BOOT=1 ;use the USB port as a serial port

The default board manifest dfrobot_firebeetle2_esp32s3.json set the upload_speed to 460800, I think it is safe to use upload speed of 921600, if you experience any upload error/problem, comment out the upload_speed = 921600 line.
I don't know why you'd want to run the Serial Monitor at such low speed of 9600bps for an MCU like ESP32, I took the liberty to change it to 115200.

Thank you, it indeed makes much more sense that way! However, still exactly the same result. Regarding the Serial Monitor, I actually tried a few different values and none of them made any difference, so I went back to 9600 because of habit, I guess.
